# Process's Virtual Bytes suddenly rise in +100M once every few hours

Tags: c++, process, byte, virtual

I have a situation where during stability the Virtual Bytes of my process, once every few hours, suddenly rise in +100 MB.

The stability is a repeating cycle, where each cycle takes 2 minutes, so this doesn't explain the sudden leap in the virtual bytes once every few hours...

The private Bytes aren't behaving the same way (they go up in a slower and a linear way...)

Has anyone encountered such behavior?
(Code is C++)

[image: virtual bytes growth]

Comment: Do you have any queues in your program,that dont get reseted in every cycle?

Comment: Or in general any dynamic data structures that don`t get completely destroyed at the end of a cycle? Maybe a log?

Comment: There exists functionality in both the [Windows CRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx) and [glibc used on Linux](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Allocation-Debugging.html) have functions to help tracing memory leaks. Then there's of course tools such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (and many others).

Comment: SOMETHING is growing (or not released). Probably not a vector, since those typically double in size. Unfortunately, other than "hunting down which part of your code does this", there isn't MUCH you can do. Certainly, we can't tell you what is going on, unless you show us SOME code (probably ALL of the code). It is also possible that you are fragmenting the heap, and the new allocations of heap is growing the virtual bytes. Again, without knowing your code, it's hopeless to tell what it may be.

Comment: Since private bytes are growing steadily, virtual bytes will also increase steadily. But the heap grows in chunks, and those chunks appear to be 100MB in size. The growth rates may not match due to memory fragmentation.